# Startup of R after reinstall fails with error message

Tags: r

I am new to R and I just installed version R 3.1.1 after uninstalling a previous version. On startup, I get the following errors

```
Error in inDL(x, as.logical(local), as.logical(now), ...) :
```

unable to load shared object 'C:/Program Files/R/R-3.1.1/library/stats/libs/x64/stats.dll':
    LoadLibrary failure:  Das angegebene Modul wurde nicht gefunden.

```
During startup - Warning message:
package ‘stats’ in options("defaultPackages") was not found 
Error in inDL(x, as.logical(local), as.logical(now), ...) : 
  unable to load shared object 'C:/Program Files/R/R-3.1.1/library/stats/libs/x64/stats.dll':
LoadLibrary failure:  Das angegebene Modul wurde nicht gefunden.
```

I reinstalled it, but this does not solve the problem. I guess, there are still old configuration files somewhere. The requested file is present in the installation directory. Where do I have to look?

Bye,
   gbpa005

P.S.: I am new to R. Operation system: Win7

Comment: stats is one of package which is loaded when you start R may be it is not installed correctly.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. How can I install it correctly? I tried de- and reinstalling and it did not work.

Comment: probably [this](https://support.rstudio.com/hc/communities/public/questions/201743623-LoadLibrary-failure-after-upgrade) can solve your problem. It is saying to remove Renviorn variale.

Comment: Sorry, I did not find how to set the Renviorn variable, but I managed to start r without errors by using the 32bit instead of 64bit version.